# Is it possible to cast to a Samsung 8 Series TV?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Is it possible to cast to a Samsung 8 Series TV?

I can successfully cast from my YouTube app on Google Pixel 3 to the TV, but not with any other apps that allow casting to Google Chromecast. I guess Samsung 8 Series does not feature built-in Chromecast, but why can I cast YouTube then? Because the TV has a YouTube app?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your TV is using DIAL protocol. You can find some info [here](https://lifehacker.com/cast-youtube-and-netflix-to-your-smart-tv-no-chromecas-1702824048)

BR

Comment: Works for Netflix and YouTube, but I've got other third party (local new stations with apps) that can cast to Chromecast without problem, but which can't cast to Samsung TV. Is that problem on the app level?

Comment: DIAL (developed by Netflix and YouTube) needs to be supported by the app, and is not the same than Chromecast protocol. Apps that use Chromecast are developed using the Chromecast SDK  (there are few protocols to send content to a second screen http://wiki.socialisingaroundmedia.com/index.php/Multiscreen_(App-to-app)_Communication)